# Cosine function period

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using the cosine function in C++ to simulate flashing for a sprite in my game. The method looks like this:

(anything in the `sf` namespace is part of the SFML graphics library)

```
void Player::update(const float& deltaTime)
{
    mAccumulatedTime += deltaTime;
    float opacity = abs(cosf(5*mAccumulatedTime)) * 255;
    static int numFlashes = 0;
    if (opacity == 255) {
        cout << ++numFlashes << endl;
    }
    mSprite.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, opacity));
}
```

So every time `opacity` is equal to 255 (basically the passing of one full period),  `numFlashes` should be incremented. The problem is, `cos()` isn't perfect, meaning it doesn't *exactly* reach 1 and 0, so the `if` condition is rarely met. If I use rough checking like `if (opacity > 255*0.9999)`, then `numFlashes` becomes really high, really fast.

Does anyone know a way to accurately check when a full period has passed? Or is that just not possible?

Comment: Is delta time in seconds or milli seconds?

Comment: @LokiAstari microseconds (SFML supports it)

Comment: @LokiAstari it's actually not supposed to be in microseconds... I just fixed that problem by dividing `deltaTime` by 1,000,000 in the method-call, so NOW it's in seconds.

Comment: Note: cosf() parameter is in radians. So it will get back to 1 every 2.pi/5 seconds (apprx 1.25 seconds). But since you are using abs() on it 0.625 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may use the following closed formula to compute `numFlashes`:

```
numFlashes = 5 * mAccumulatedTime / pi.
```

This follows from the fact that the period of the function `abs(cos(x))` is `pi` and, if an oscillating function in variable `x` has a period `T`, then the number of oscillations, `n`, is given by the formula:

```
n = x / T.
```

Thus, your function definition may be corrected, and even simplified, as follows:

```
const float PI = acosf(-1);

void Player::update(const float& deltaTime)
{
    mAccumulatedTime += deltaTime;
    float opacity = abs(cosf(5*mAccumulatedTime)) * 255;
    int numFlashes = 5 * mAccumulatedTime / PI;
    cout << numFlashes << endl;
    mSprite.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, opacity));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it critical that you flash on the maximum? You could change it to flash as it crosses a value if not.

```
double CalcOpacity( const float& accTime )
{
    return (cosf(PERIOD*mAccumulatedTime)) * AMPLITUDE;
}

void Player::update(const float& deltaTime)
{
    float old_opacity = CalcOpacity( mAccumulatedTime );
    mAccumulatedTime += deltaTime;
    float opacity = CalcOpacity( mAccumulatedTime );
    static int numFlashes = 0;
    if ( ( old_opacity < 0 ) && ( opacity >= 0 ) ) {// and the other direction
        cout << ++numFlashes << endl;
    }
    mSprite.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, abs(opacity)));
}
```